# Using Python and os.kill on chrome?

Tags: python, google-chrome, syntax, process, kill

So I'm having some trouble figuring out the syntax of the os.kill() function in Python. I need it to kill chrome when there are too many tabs open, say ten or a hundred. I've looked all already but even the documentation doesn't seem to make sense.

NOTE: I'm counting tabs as I open them, not accesses some chrome API.

Comment: What don't you understand?  Are you actually asking how to find Chrome's pids?

Comment: I know the PID, but the second argument is the mystery to me.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_(command) http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#module-signal

Comment: Okay that seems to make sense, but now it looks like chrome changes PID sometimes.

Comment: Chrome uses multiple processes.